# Is there any reason why the library OMPtrace does not work on large codes?

Tags: multithreading, fortran, openmp, profiling, flang

I have a code that I parallelized using **OpenMP**. I want to make sure that the threads deployed follow the same **sequence diagram** that I have in mind. In order to do that, I looked for an efficient tool (library, software,..) and found the lib **OMPTrace** which is a simple tool for tracing and visualizing **OpenMP** program execution. it's shown [here](https://github.com/passlab/omptrace) how to install and use it. The file I want to compile is called `hecese_OpenMP.f90` (**Fortran**).
I executed the following block of commands in order to vizualize the behaviour of the threads.

```
flang -g -mp hecese_OpenMP.f90 -L/home/hakim/llvm-openmp-install/lib -o heceseflang
14 h 40
objdump -d heceseflang >heceseflang.objdump
14 h 40
LD_PRELOAD=/home/hakim/llvm-openmp-install/lib/libomp.so:/home/hakim/llvm-openmp/BUILD/omptrace/build/libomptrace.so ./heceseflang
```

and it shows:

```
140557273808912: ompt_event_release_nest_lock_last: wait_id=140558880879816, codeptr_ra=0x411abe 
140557273808912: ompt_event_wait_nest_lock: wait_id=140558880879816, hint=0, impl=2, codeptr_ra=0x41199f 
140557273808912: ompt_event_acquired_nest_lock_first: wait_id=140558880879816, codeptr_ra=0x41199f 
140557273808912: ompt_event_release_nest_lock_last: wait_id=140558880879816, codeptr_ra=0x411abe 
Erreur de segmentation (core dumped)
```

I tested the library on a **hello_world** program and it worked perfectly.
I tried to reproduce the **sequence diagram** I have in mind and it gave me: [image]

The problem is that if I compile my code with `gfortran` and execute it, I don't get a **segmentation fault** (everything works fine) but when I try with **OMPTrace** I get a **segmentation fault**.

My question is very simple. Does the problem come from the library itself (knowing that it worked for the **hello_world** code) or it can come from my code (knowing that it works without the lib) ? I doubt that this library does not support large codes. My code contains 1200 lines.

Comment: 1200 lines is a very small code.

Comment: @VladimirF yes, it's true but maybe 1200 is larger than what OMPTrace is waiting for.

Comment: That is extremely unlikely.

Comment: You write: "My question is very simple. Does the problem come from the library itself (knowing that it worked for the hello_world code) or it can come from my code (knowing that it works without the lib) ? " Like in your previous question: please share a MWE showing the problem, we need more to work with.

Comment: Why do you tag gfortran when clearly using flang?

Comment: @VladimirF I tag gfortran because as I said in my question, I succeded to compile my code with gfortran.

Comment: On the web page you link to it says "Prerequisite

OpenMP implementation that supports OMPT interface, which is the LLVM OpenMP runtime". Is this the case for gfortran? I have no idea. gfortran is not referenced on the page at all.

Comment: @IanBush The OP is using flang for that, not gfortran. Hence my comment. The code also happens to work when compiled with gfortran, but that is only tangential.

Comment: @VladimirF The OP says "The problem is that if I compile my code with gfortran and execute it, I don't get a segmentation fault (everything works fine) but when I try with OMPTrace I get a segmentation fault." I read that as when it is compiled with gfortran without omptrace it works, but when it is compiled with gfortran *and* omptrace it segfaults. But yes, on rereading, it is ambiguous.